# C program file transfer, printing out server side errors on client side

Tags: c, networking, server, client

I'm creating a program that requests a file from a server and sends back the file, creating a new file and writing the contents of that file into the new file. Everything is working perfectly except server side error messages (i.e. file doesn't exist) should be printed on the client side. Can anyone give me a clue on how to accomplish this? I'm new to C, but willing to learn more. My main problem is that if I send the message directly, the client side doesn't know that it's an error and is going to finish out and create a file and write the message into that file. I was thinking I need to send back a -1, so when client calls recv, it gets back -1 as the length and prints a message.

Here's my client:

```
  ssize_t recvx(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len) {
    int var = recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
    if(var != -1)
    {
      return var;
    } else {
      printf("%s \n","Did not receive.");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *rp, *result;
    int bytes_received;
    int s;
    char *server;
    char *port;
    char *file;
    int fd = -1; //file descriptor
    int bytes_written;

    if (argc==4)
    {
      server = argv[1];
      port = argv[2];
      file = argv[3];
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid # of arguments\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Translate host name into peer's IP address */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    if ((s = getaddrinfo(server, port, &hints, &result)) != 0 )
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: getaddrinfo: %s\n", argv[0], gai_strerror(s));
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Iterate through the address list and try to connect */
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
      if ((s = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol)) == -1 )
      {
        continue;
      }
      if (connect(s, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
 {
        break;
      }
      close(s);
    }

    if (rp == NULL)
    {
      perror("stream-talk-client: connect");
      exit(1);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result); 
    /*send lines of text */ 
   send(s, file, sizeof(file), 0);


   while(bytes_received != 0)
    {
      bytes_received = recvx(s, buf, 20);
      if(bytes_received == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client Error: Error receiving file \n");
        exit(1);
      } else {
        if(fd == -1)
        {
          fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
          if(fd == -1)
          {
           fprintf(stderr,"Client Error: Open failed \n");
           exit(1);
         }
         bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
         if(bytes_written == -1)
         {
           fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
           exit(1);
         }
       } else {
         bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
         if(bytes_written == -1)
         {
           fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
           exit(1);
         }
       }
     }
   }
   if(close(fd) != 0)
   {
     printf("%s \n", "Client Error: File did not close successfully");
     exit(1);
   }


   close(s);

   return 0;
 }
```

Here's my server:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *rp, *result;
    char filename[MAX_LINE];
    int s, new_s;
    int bytes_transferred;
    int fd; //file descriptor
    struct stat statBuffer; //to hold file info
    off_t offset = 0;

    /* Build address data structure */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    /* Get local address info */
    if ((s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result)) != 0 )
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: getaddrinfo: %s\n", argv[0], gai_strerror(s));
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Iterate through the address list and try to perform passive open */
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
      if ((s = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol)) == -1 )
      {
        continue;
      }

      if (!bind(s, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen))
      {
        break;
      }
      close(s);
    }
    if (rp == NULL)
    {
      perror("stream-talk-server: bind");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(s, MAX_PENDING) == -1)
    {
      perror("stream-talk-server: listen");
      close(s);
      exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    /* Wait for connection, then receive and print text */
    while(1)
     { 
      if ((new_s = accept(s, rp->ai_addr, &(rp->ai_addrlen))) < 0)
      {
        perror("stream-talk-server: accept");
        close(s);
        exit(1);
      }
      while(bytes_transferred == recv(new_s,filename,sizeof(filename),0))
      {
        if(bytes_transferred == -1)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: Error receiving filename \n");
          exit(1);
        }
      }
      printf("%s \n", filename);
      fd =open(filename,O_RDONLY);

      if(fd < 0)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"Server Error: file doesn't exist\n");
        exit(1);
     }
     else
     {
       printf("%s \n","file opened successfully");
     }
     /*get info from file descriptor (fd) and store it in statBuffer struct */
     fstat(fd, &statBuffer);
     bytes_transferred = sendfile(new_s,fd,&offset,statBuffer.st_size);
     if(bytes_transferred == -1)
     {
       fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: File not transferred successfully");
     }
     else
     {
       printf("%s \n", "File transferred successfully");
     }
     if(close(fd) != 0)
     {
       fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: File not close successfully");
     }
     else{
       break;
     }
   }
   close(new_s);

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. My specific problem is figuring out how to send an error message back to the client to print out. (i.e. Server Error: file doesn't exist). if I send the message directly, client receives something and stores it where the file's going to be stored. Don't want that, so I was wondering if there is some way for the server to indicate to the client that the file doesn't exist and the client printing out that this error occurred on the server side. Thanks

Comment: In that case, [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) will return a value which is negative. Check the [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and if it is the case of a file not found, return some value to client, and make client check its return values before it writes to the file ? If the file doesn't exists, then the Open system call in the server will fail and errno will be set to **ENOENT**

Comment: you need an application protocol. That is, a set of messages/responses the client and server expect to see from each other. For your small project here, it doesn't have to be very complicated.

Comment: It may help to look at the documentation for application protocols that already support the features you want, such as HTTP and FTP.

Comment: ah ok. so I should only recv if there's no error message on the server. I'll look up the documentation for the application protocols. I was thinking I needed to store the errno in something and send it back to client when they recv and when recv returns number of bytes returned which I want to be -1 because no file exists, but it returns 0 because no file was sent, lol.

Comment: You'll never know if there was an error on the server side unless you receive it in the client. `recv()` returned zero because the peer closed the cionnection.

Comment: Imagine it like the post; at the moment it sounds like the server sends you a blank letter if it can't find the file. You want it to send a letter saying "Error: Can't find file".

Comment: But then how would you tell the difference between whether the server couldn't find the file, and whether it **could** find the file but some joker put the words "Error: Can't find file" in the file?

Comment: Thanks guys for your ideas. I just added the whole code so you can get the whole picture of what I'm trying to do. As stated before, everything works perfectly. However one of the requirements is that all error messages display on the client side in the format Server Error: or Client Error: I looked into those protocols and seem a little out of scope for this class. the only hint my teacher gave us is read the man pages, which I've done and can't find anything applicable. Also, looked through Beej's. Maybe with the whole picture here, someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the long posts guys. I just wanted to add that another reason I need to get the error back to client is because if file doesn't exist in server, both sides should close. The client side tries to open a file and if it never got a file, it still creates a blank one. It's only supposed to create a file if it receives one and it doesn't exist on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're implementing is something along the lines of what HTTP and FTP servers do. Both have specific, but rather different, protocol steps for handling errors. The HTTP case is easy to understand -- the server doesn't just send back the file: it sends back a bunch of headers, then the file. The client can inspect the headers to know whether there is any file data to follow.

In a very simple case, I suspect you could implement something similar in your code without too much work -- just have the server send a one-byte response code before the rest of the file. You could have 0 (for example) to indicate that a valid file follows, and other numbers to indicate particular error conditions. The client would just read the data as it currently does, but if the first byte isn't zero, it knows that nothing else that follows (if anything does) is valid.

Or you could arrange that if the first byte was not zero, the text that follows is not the expected file, but an error message, which should be displayed by the client.

You could extent such a scheme with as much complexity as you like, until you end up with HTTP :)

Comment: ah ok I see what you're saying. I'm slightly confused on how I would implement receive then. Whatever is received is stored in char buf array and recv returns the numbers of bytes received (or -1 on failure). There may be anything in the file I'm receiving. How would I differentiate if it's the file I'm receiving or an error code. For example, if I used -1 because that's indication of failure on receiving a file, it would treat it as something to store in buf and write it to a new file.

Comment: If `recv()` returns -1 (as its return value), then there's no point inspecting any data that got placed into its buffer -- an error of some sort has occurred, outside of your communication protocol. Your client just needs to report this, perhaps querying `errno` for more details. My proposal is to put a success/failure code into the data returned by your server, perhaps as the first byte. The client would treat all the returned data as data, except the first byte, which is the success/failure code. This mechanism of reporting status is _in addition to_ anything provided by the `recv()` call.

Comment: ah ha I got it. Before my while loop, I called recvx and if it equals 0 right off the bat, then I didn't receive anything and I can exit. But what if it's an empty file? Would that still have some bytes to transfer even if the file's blank?

Comment: ah ok good to know. The first byte I'd be sending back would be located in filename[0], (buf[0] on the receiving end)? I printed that value out when i tried to store errno into that and kept getting garbage characters. And hardcoding in error numbers to send back yield compiler errors. need const *void as argument.

Comment: Try storing errno+32, and then subtracting 32 on the receiving end. That will shift the errno value into the displayable ASCII range. This is a bit cheeky because, in principle, errno values could be too large to fit into a single byte. More elegantly, perhaps, write errno as a four-digit hex number, and use the first four bytes of your returned data for that value. At any rate, a gibberish display does not, by itself, indicate a problem -- errno values are usually two small to be treated as displayable characters.

Comment: thanks for your response. I got some more hints from my professor. He said I don't need to send the error message back to the client. I need the client to detect that the server has closed the socket (after I see that the file doesn't exist I close the socket on the server side). I can't figure out how to determine if the remote socket has closed. If I just simply read or write from "s", the client sides still open and executes accordingly. Is there a new function to check the status of the server socket (new_s)?

Comment: oh h wait, just reading up on read() some more and it says that 0 indicates the socket was closed. I was thinking that would be -1, but it's technically not an error. It means the socket was closed properly (orderly shutdown)